# What is the best solution to create user notifications on adding new record into model with Django Channels?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

There is an object that has a comment option, as there is an option to subscribe to notifications on adding/deleting/editing comments to this object. I came up with one solution - each object is a group where subscribed users are stored and when there is a removal/addition/edition of a comment to this group happens, a notification is sent to the group of this object.

So, is this right solution?

Comment: there are several options to solve this problem, your approach sounds ok. Does it work for you? Do you have a specific problem we can help you with like codewise? General questions like "what is the best...." are hard to answer since they require more knowlage of the project and so on. Please try to ask specific questions which can be answered.

Comment: @hansTheFranz so my i need know what is best practice for my problem. So i found out quite good solution its ok, thanks